# Bundling javascript files in MVC 4.0

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to bundle javascript files in my web application to increase performance. I'm trying to load a minified version of jQuery as an example but when I run the web application jQuery is not loaded.

**Bundle config:**

```
  public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/","jquery-1.8.2.min.js"));
//Also tried this:
//bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

**Master page:**

```
@using System.Configuration
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var screenRefreshTime = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScreenRefreshTime"].ToString()';
        screenRefreshTime = parseInt(screenRefreshTime);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are loading the scripts in body of master page. Are you trying to access the scripts before it is loaded. Kindly place the loading of scripts in head section just to see is it changing any thing....

Comment: What error did you get in the browser? 404?

Comment: have you tried calling the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" before the renderbody()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to include min when you are create bundle for it.I am assuming you have jquery.1.8.2.js and jquery.1.8.2.min.js in same folder and file names are same except "min" word Ex: jquery.1.8.2.js,jquery.1.8.2.min.js. Instead of include directory you can try direct include working fine. The code like this

```
  public class BundleConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("jquery-1.8.2.js"));

    }
}
```

Also need to mention bundling works only on Release mode if you need check it on debug mode you need to enable optimizations.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

To call it

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of IncludeDirectory is the search pattern so try *.js

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/", "*.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

Or use Include rather than IncludeDirectory:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both, still doesn't work.Getting this error in developer mode in Chrome - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: If you inspect the html is there any jquery outputted at the button of the body?

Comment: At the bottom it has script tags refrencing all .*js files

Comment: Try to place @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") at the top.May be your render body have jquery code